# slice a datatable for daterange , sum up counts and create a custom table?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

Is there any easy way to slice a datatable for a range and sum up counts for a range?

let say I have below datatable

```
Date    Count
5/9/2016    5
5/10/2016   1
5/11/2016   2
5/12/2016   4
5/13/2016   3
5/14/2016   2
5/15/2016   1
5/16/2016   4
```

If I slice it by 2 then it will club 2 rows ..something like

```
DateRange           Count
5/9/2016-5/10/2016  6
5/11/2016-5/12/2016 6
5/13/2016-5/14/2016 5
5/15/2016-5/16/2016 5
```

If I slice it by 3 then it will club 3 rows ..something like

```
DateRange           Count
5/9/2016-5/11/2016  8
5/12/2016-5/14/2016 9
5/15/2016-5/16/2016 5
```

I am trying to show my data in a asp:Chart (StackedColumn) chart for a date range. date range varies between 7,15,30,60,90,150,365 days ..almost each day there are some data entries and there are a custom date control to select date also . let say a user select a date range for 200 days , for 200 days their will 200 records . now is there any way to club up the data and show in that chart .Currently I am trying to do it by month but as I know there are a custom date range so I need to come up with a different workaround , any help on it .

```
 public DataTable GetTable()
    {
        // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Columns.Add("R", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        for (int i = 0; i <= dayschunk; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-i).ToString("MMM-dd"), new Random().Next(0, 99), new Random().Next(0, 99));
        }
        var results = from row in table.AsEnumerable()
                      group row by new { Date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date").Month } into rowgroup
                      select new
                      {
                          rowgroup.Key.Date,
                          Remidiated = rowgroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("R")),
                          Stucked = rowgroup.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("C"))
                      };
        DataTable filtered = new DataTable();
        filtered.Columns.Add("DateRange", typeof(int));
        filtered.Columns.Add("R", typeof(int));
        filtered.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.Date), item.Remidiated, item.Stucked);
        }

        //table.Rows.Add(2,new DateTime(2016, 05, 02), 50, 50);
        //table.Rows.Add(2,new DateTime(2016, 05, 07), 3, 4);
        //table.Rows.Add(2,new DateTime(2016, 05, 05), 16, 10);
        return filtered;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this using `Select` overload to pass an index and creating chunks with the given size.

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Columns.Add("DateRange", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));


int chunk = 2;  
        
result = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row,i) => new {gid= i/chunk, row}) 
    .GroupBy(x=>x.gid)
    .Select(x=>  
            {
                var row= result.NewRow();
            
                row["DateRange"] = string.Format("{0}-{1}", x.First().row.Field<DateTime>("Date"), x.Last().row.Field<DateTime>("Date"));
                row["Count"]=  x.Sum(r=>r.row.Field<int>("R"));
                return row;
            }).CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Check this [`Example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/snB7oE)

**Note:** I have not applied output formatting, but you could this easily and I will leave it to you.